# Knockoutjs nested view models

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js

I'am using Knockoutjs and have a problem getting access to root/parent models data in a submodel. The data I get via Ajax.

The Ajax success creates a new WeekViewModel and this creates a few RowViewModels. And here is my Problem, at this time `week` is not defined. 

After the site is rendered, I can get the Infos over `week`.
The only solution I've found is pasting the parent and root into the submodel.
But this works not so well cause at the initialsation, the parent is a plain js Obeject. After the site is rendered, and I will paste another rowViewModel from a click event, the parent is a knockout object.

Can anyone give me some suggestions where I'va made a mistake? Or whats a way to get this fixed?!

Here's my code:

```
$(function() {
    var week;
    var weekData;

    $.when(
        $.get('js/dataNew.json', function (res) {
            weekData = res;
        }),
        // another calls ...

        ).then(function () {
            week = new WeekViewModel(weekData);
            ko.applyBindings(week, $('#content').get(0));
    });

    function WeekViewModel(data){
        var self = this;
        var mapping = {
            'Rows': {
                create: function(options) {
                    return new RowViewModel(options.data, self);
                }
            }
        };
        this.allDays = allDays;
        this.cats = new ko.observableDictionary();
        // more code ...
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, this);
    };

    function RowViewModel(row, parent){
        var self = this;
        var mapping = {
            'RowDays': {
                create: function(options) {
                    return new DayModel(options.data, self, parent);
                }
            }
        };
        if(row){
            if(!row.DisplayName) {
                // need data from the root here
                // parent.cats <---
            }
        }
        // more code ...
        ko.mapping.fromJS(row, mapping, this);
    }

    // another submodel ...
});
```

Update:
fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/23750/

updated fiddle with html:
http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/23753/

Comment: It would help us help you if you change your code into a small repro, preferably with a runnable Stack Snippet. I can currently *kind of* see where your problem lies, but there's a bit too much code missing to give concrete advice.

Comment: @jeroen, a fiddle is here: jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/23750

Comment: can you supply the html that you are binding too, as well? In the fiddle.

Comment: @JasonWilczak the html is very complex. But it doesnt matters here, cause I need the parent/root context in the javascript :-/

Comment: You should be passing the cats observable into each `RowViewModel` from the `WeekViewModel`. This would solve your problem and prevent an unhealthy dependency between `WeekViewModel` and `RowViewModel`.

Comment: So, week will not be definited until "new WeekViewModel(weekData);" is done.  That doesn't happen until it goes through all the interior functions.  I logged after several points, the term 'object' refers to the week var: always start object is undefined
(index):179 WeekViewModel start object is undefined
4(index):179 RowViewModel start object is undefined
(index):179 After week initialized in always object is defined

Comment: What line, in your code, are you getting the issue?

Comment: Thanks for our support here! I've set breakpoints here: http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/23764/ @JasonWilczak

Comment: So I checked out your fiddle, the data seems to be there, no problem, here is my updated version with debuggers commented and logging the parent.cats value: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonwilczak/LkqTU/23767/)